# Using SpongyCastle Provider on AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, spongycastle

I am trying to write an ECDH code for my android app. 
As a starting point, I managed to instal lSpongyCastle Jar's on my AndroidStudion, but now I am having an issue when I run:

```
KeyPairGenerator aliceKeyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDH", "SC");
```

It keeps saying that there is no such provider, however I have added

```
  Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
```

to my code, and I have added the

```
implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0'
```

to my gradle.

I have tried different provider names (such as "BC") but all gave me the same error 'NoSuchProviderException'

I have tried reading everywhere without success, please let me know what I am doing wrong and what else I should do.

Thank you!

PS
Needless to say, other functions of SpongyCastle are working properly, so I believe I have installed the library successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Which API Version are you using? Google changed the behavior of inserting and using security providers. I do not have an actual answer for your question, but that looks like it.

Google states state since Android P the prefer AndroidOpenSSL as security provider internally and they deprecate some BC provider functionality. Using getInstance() with a given provider (e.g. "BC" or "SC") will throw NoSuchAlgorithmException for apps targeting Android P or later.

They propose to just not use an explicit provider in getInstance().

see https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/cryptography-changes-in-android-p.html and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography#deprecated-functionality

Also I do see in my experiments on Android that spongycastle may not need to be added at position 1 as AndroidOpenSSL provides now a lot of security algorithms (just do `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());` if you really need some stuff from it).